# host application Windows workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, workflow

can someone help me for making a host application to run windows workflows from dll files, as like in MS CRM 4.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a host app written for you. It's called [Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx).